# Return collections from Mongo using a MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm currently working on a group project. We're using the MEAN stack to create a simple web application but are running into some issues with returning data from the mongo database.

We're trying to return all documents in a collection stored in a mongo db (hosted at mongolab) but running into issues with retrieving the data.

We're using the following Mongoose code within our node server to create our schema:

```
var challengeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
description: String,
difficulty: Number,
numberOfTimesCompleted: Number,
comments: [{user: String, body: String, date: Date }]
});

var Challenge = mongoose.model('Challenge', challengeSchema);
```

Using this schema, a collection called "challenges" is added to the database.

While we're having no difficulties in adding documents to the collection, when we try to return all the documents from this collection, nothing returns (it times out).

This is the code we're currently using to query the database:

```
exports.getChallenges = function (req, res){

    var challengeList = {};

    Challenge.find(function (err, Challenge) {
        if (err)
        challengeList = Challenge;
        console.log(Challenge);
        res.send(challengeList);
    });    
};
```

We were thinking the issue had something to do with the fact that the collection is called "challenges" and our model is called "Challenge." After playing with the code for a while we weren't able to make much progress.

Any ideas what we might be doing wrong? All of us are new to mongo and node and feel like we are most likely making a simple mistake. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "nothing returns" - do you mean that the `res.send` never successfully completes? and is `challengeList` a standard js object or a Mongoose object?

Comment: Res.send never completes (the $http GET request eventually times out), and nothing is ever logged to the console. ChallengeList is a standard JavaScript object.

Comment: Is there a reason why you name the second `find` callback parameter (`Challenge`) the same as your object? e.g. any reason *not* to do `Challenge.find(function(err, chall)` or similar instead?

Comment: No, it was an arbitrary assignment (maybe a bad choice). Replacing it with 'challenges' seemed to have no effect though.

Comment: Ah man- I've found the issue. And now I feel stupid. I simply needed to deal with the if (err) statement I made (either delete it or make it log or otherwise handle it). After doing so everything works like a charm. Sorry for wasting your time Jeff! But thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From reading the Mongoose docs, it looks like the mongo collection name will be induced from the model name, unless you supply it as the third parameter to the `mongoose.model` method.

So in your example, you might try:

```
var Challenge = mongoose.model('Challenge', challengeSchema, 'challenges');
```

The docs for that mongoose method are here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model

In addition, it looks like you're not supplying any conditions to the `mongoose.find` method.  Here's the API documentation for that: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find.  So you'd want something like:

```
Challenge.find({find_my_criteria:'here'},function (err, challenges) {
    res.send(challenges);
});
```

...obviously you would want to substitute your actual conditions/criteria with something from the `req`, as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Jeff- unfortunately this didn't resolve the issue. I'll look into the docs a little deeper.

Comment: just updated — looks like you were missing conditions for the `find` method

Comment: The issue was I had just pulled the code format directly from the [mongoose quickstart](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) and didn't properly deal with the error case. Thanks for your time and effort Jeff! This wouldn't have been solved tonight had you not spurred me with those questions.